# Why does "exec non-existent-file" exits the shell when in a script that is sourced?

Tags: bash

The documentation for `exec` says that it will exit the shell in case of error if the current shell is non-interactive and `execfail` option is not set.

I noticed a strange behavior in an interactive bash shell which I can't explain with the docs though.  This command

```
exec non-existent-file
```

produces an error message and the shell stays active, as expected.  But if I put the same command into a file and `source` that file, the current shell will be exited by the failing exec.

Could someone help me understand why this happens?

Comment: I have no idea why this is.  You're correct; sourcing a file *does* execute it interactively.  Could it be you found a bug in `bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I feel, it is a bug. Below is some kind of "detective story".

Yes, in the `exec.def` code, we see:

```
if (subshell_environment || (interactive == 0 && no_exit_on_failed_exec == 0))
  exit_shell (exit_value);
```

so, `exec` would cause exiting the shell
a) on non-interactive shell with `false` "no_exit_on_failed_exec"
b) when `exec` is being run in subshell

For interactive shell, if the command exist, the shell is replaced by
the command invoked:

> exec
>
> This shell builtin replaces the current process with a specified
>   command. Normally, when the shell encounters a command, it forks off a
>   child process to actually execute the command.
>   **Using the exec builtin,
>   the shell does not fork, and the command exec'ed replaces the shell**.
>   When used in a script, therefore, **it forces an exit from the script
>   when the exec'ed command terminates**.
>
> Example 15-24. Effects of exec
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> exec echo "Exiting \"$0\" at line $LINENO."   # Exit from script here.
> # $LINENO is an internal Bash variable set to the line number it's on.
> **# The following lines never execute.**
> ```
>
> http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#EXECREF

**`source` command does not call subshell** - it forces all the commands to execute **in your current, active shell** (it is used, e.g., for setting variables - not for some subshell that will exit, but for your current shell). So after executing command both with `source` and directly in the shell, your shell will terminate (it is the expected behaviour).

> When a script is run using `source' it runs within the existing shell,
>   any variables created or modified by the script will remain available
>   after the script completes.
>   http://ss64.com/bash/source.html

I've compiled `bash-4.2` and 've run it in `gdb` debugger.

These are the last commands that being executed before exit:

```
(gdb) 
bash: exec: non-existing-file: не найден
163       exit_value = EX_NOTFOUND; /* As per Posix.2, 3.14.6 */
(gdb) 
165       goto failed_exec;
(gdb) 
235   FREE (command);
(gdb) 
237   if (subshell_environment || (interactive == 0 && no_exit_on_failed_exec == 0))
(gdb)
238     exit_shell (exit_value);
(gdb)
[Inferior 1 (process 4034) exited with code 0177]
```

Printing the variables:

```
(gdb) p subshell_environment 
$1 = 0
(gdb) p interactive
$2 = 0
(gdb) p no_exit_on_failed_exec 
$3 = 0
```

It turns out, the shell is non-interactive (`interactive=0`) while sourcing the built-in `exec`. This is the reason for such behaviour.
It contradicts the documented behaviour, so, one may say, you've found a bug.

The change to `non-interactive`, `interactive=0`, happens here (`evalfile.c`):

```
interactive:
Old value = 1
New value = 0
_evalfile (filename=0xa014c8 "exec1.sh", flags=14)
at evalfile.c:226
223  if (flags & FEVAL_NONINT)
224    interactive = 0;
```

because of `flags=14`.
`flags` are set a level higher, in the function `source_file` (`evalfile.c`):

```
#1  0x0000000000485dcf in source_file (filename=0x9fb8c8 "exec1.sh", sflags=0)

338  flags = FEVAL_BUILTIN|FEVAL_UNWINDPROT|FEVAL_NONINT;
339  if (sflags)
340    flags |= FEVAL_NOPUSHARGS;
341  /* POSIX shells exit if non-interactive and file error. */
342  if (posixly_correct && interactive_shell == 0 && executing_command_builtin == 0)
343    flags |= FEVAL_LONGJMP;
344  rval = _evalfile (filename, flags);
```

And the defines are:

```
#define FEVAL_BUILTIN       0x002
#define FEVAL_UNWINDPROT    0x004
#define FEVAL_NONINT        0x008
```

-> flags 1110 =14.

So, as I understand, it is a bug: `source` executes commands in the current shell, but sets flag `FEVAL_NONINT 0x008` - non-interactive
(bug here):
`evalfile.c`, in `source_file`:

```
338 flags = FEVAL_BUILTIN|FEVAL_UNWINDPROT|FEVAL_NONINT;
```

I've created an issue on a bug tracker:

http://savannah.gnu.org/support/index.php?108980

Would watch it.

---

EDIT1:
[As bash supporter commented on the ticket](http://savannah.gnu.org/support/?108980#comment1)

> "The shell is not currently interactive when reading a file argument
>   to the source builtin (interactive == 0), though the shell itself is
>   interactive (interactive_shell == 1)."

Also, as he said, this behaviour is likely not to be changed in the nearest future.

The question seems closed now.